# How to extract individual wave component information of a signal?

Tags: matlab, fft, wavelet, cross-correlation

The signal I am interested in is a vector of wind speed and a vector of time which form a ten minute wind speed profile. How can I extract information on the individual waves which combine to form the full ten minute signal (eg. 10 waves with mean speed 9m/s and frequency 1hz and so on),so i end up with a list of all constituent waves and their frequency, max/min values etc. I have tried cross-correlation comparing a 'test' wave of a few seconds with the ten minute vector but this doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to compute the Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) of your signal. This can be done by using Matlab's built-in `fft` function (documentation [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html)).

Comment: I have tried this but the fft signal is too noisy to interpret.

Comment: Have you tried multiple n (transform length) values? This might improve your results.

Comment: No i havent tried this, what do you mean by transform length?

Comment: okay I have done this and have a kind of interperetable magnitude response, how do i convert the peaks in the magnitude response into the absolute values of equivalent peaks in the time domain?

Comment: I suggest checking out this Researchgate post: https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_I_find_the_amplitude_of_a_real_signal_using_fft_function_in_Matlab